# TCP/IP MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab, tcp

I am trying to run a simulation model in MATLAB which takes input via TCP/IP from python code and sends back some data to the python code. I am unable to sync both the times. My TCP/IP is sending data with a different time interval(0.02) while my simulation model runs with a different interval(0.08). I tried to fix the step size in simulation model configuration but nothing helps. Can anybody explain the same?

Answer (score 0):

Usually with a TCP/IP connection, there is a handshake performed to ensure data was successfully transferred before the next packet is sent.

for example python would do the following

```
    # Setup Socket for data transfer
    TransferSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = 'localhost'
    port = '5050'
    TransferSocket.connect((host,port))

    # Get data to send (this case a text file)
    f = open("file.txt","rb")

    # send message
    chunk = f.read(1024)
    while (chunk):
        TransferSocket.send(chunk)  # Send data
        Rmsg = TransferSocket.recv(1024) # wait for handshake before sending more
        if Rmsg.decode() == "ACK":
            chunk = f.read(1024)
        else:
            pass
```

A package is sent and immediately waits for a reply before sending the next package

In matlab

```
tcpipServer = tcpip('localhost',5050,'NetworkRole','Server');
            set(tcpipServer,'OutputBufferSize',8);
            set(tcpipServer, 'BytesAvailableFcnCount',512);
            set(tcpipServer, 'BytesAvailableFcnMode','byte');
            set(tcpipServer, 'BytesAvailableFcn', @(h,e)recmessage(h,e));
```

From here whenever a package is received from python, the function recmessage will run The function is below.

```
    function recmessage(h,e)
        message = fread(tcpipServer,tcpipServer.BytesAvailable);
        % Do whatever else you want
        fwrite(tcpipServer,"ACK");
    end
```

From here the 'ok' will be sent back to python and repeat.

This is a basic example for data transfer. For what you want it would most likely be data instead of an 'ok' code.

But yeah, If you setup a handshake instead of trying to time them, it should fix your problem.